# Android: can I call a Log.i method from the onDraw method of a view?

Tags: android, ondraw

I am trying to call the `Log.i` method to test the refresh rate for the View:

```
public class GameView extends View {

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Log.i("OnDraw","ping");
    invalidate();
    }
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
public class GameUI extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

GameView gameview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameview = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameview);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public GameView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}
```

This may help you..........

Comment: If this view doesn't do any drawing on its own, set this flag to allow further optimizations.

for more information try this link.
http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3AAndroid.Views.View.SetWillNotDraw%28System.Boolean%29